# gulp obfuscate and the dependancy on multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, gulp

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-obfuscate plugin to obfuscate my code. [Ionic application]
I have my angular module defines as 
var mod1=angular.module .... in file a.js
&
I access it as mod1.factory ... in file b.js

Now,when I obfuscate the above code mod1 in a.js is getting changed to some dummy string but mod1 in b.js is as is. 
Now when I try to use as mod1.factory ... am getting undefined error in b.js as mod1 is not defined !
Am i doing anything wrong ?
I am new to gulp here.
Help is appreciated !